# How to plot different shades of a color for each point in a scatter plot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, scatter-plot, scatter

I am trying to plot a scatter plot where each point in the scatter plot should correspond to a particular **shade** of a given color of my **choice**. The mpl documentation states that if I set something like:

```
color = '0.7'
```

it gives me a shade of grey with that scaled intensity of `0.7`. I am reading the intensity of the colours from an array with values between 0 and 1 and each value corresponds to the intensity of that point in the scatter plot. My code below is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import math

tsne_embeddings = np.load("tsne_embeddings.npy")
labels = np.load('labels.npy')
weights = np.load('weights.npy')
# Scale the weights from 0 to 1
max_weight = max(weights)
min_weight = min(weights)
weights = (weights - min_weight)/(max_weight - min_weight)
print(tsne_embeddings.shape)
x = list(tsne_embeddings[:,0])
y = list(tsne_embeddings[:,1])
labels = list(labels)

weights = np.round(weights,decimals=2)
weights = (np.exp(weights) - 1)/(np.exp(1) - 1)
weights = list(weights)
print(min(weights),max(weights))

for i, shade in enumerate(weights):
    plt.scatter(x[i],y[i],color=shade,marker = '+')

plt.show()
```

I am scaling those weights exponentially hoping for a better variation.
So, essentially, my questions are:

1. How do I change the color to say shades of blue or red or green as opposed to just greyscale?
2. Is the approach which I follow for greyscale correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make your approach work for shades of grey, you need to convert the value to a string, so `plt.scatter(..., color=str(shade))`.

The more standard way of working with matplotlib would be to directly use the weights, without rescaling them to the range `0` to `1`, use a colormap, and calling scatter directly with the arrays. The weights go into the `c=` parameter. For grey values this would be `plt.scatter(x, y, c=weights, cmap='Greys', marker='+')`. An additional feature of matplotlib is that with this information it can automatically create a colorbar mapping the grey values to the corresponding weight. If only one scatter plot is created, `plt.colorbar()` without parameters will show this colorbar.

Similar colormaps exist of 'Purples', 'Blues', 'Greens', 'Oranges', 'Reds', ...  See the [official doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) with a complete list. If the range between light and dark goes the wrong way, appending '_r' to the name will use the opposite color range (so, 'Greys' goes from white to black, while 'Greys_r' goes from black to white).

Here is a working example using the values from 1 to 10 for the three arrays:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(1, 11)
y = np.arange(1, 11)
weights = np.arange(1, 11)
plt.scatter(x, y, c=weights, cmap='Greys', marker='+')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Answer (score 1):

You can use colormaps in python to generate different shades of blue green etc.
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html
I am using Blues color map here

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(weights), vmax=max(weights))
cmap = mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=mpl.cm.Blues)
for i, xi in enumerate(x):
    plt.scatter(x[i],y[i],color=cmap.to_rgba(i+1),marker = '+')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! How do I exactly pass my weights? Or is that passed automatically in the norm = mpl.colors. ......... line, when the max and min is called? Basically my question is how does my `scatter` know from where tp pick the weights?